# App permissions on a Codename One app: alert, ask, code for granted and denied, ask again if denied

Tags: codenameone

Is there any article in the Codename One blog about managing permissions on Android (7+) and iOS? I would do something like other apps, that is: alert the user that a permission is necessary, then prompt for permission, then run a code if the permission is granted and another if permission is denied. In the second case, I would offer the user a way to ask permission again.

I read something about that in the past, maybe in the Codename One blog, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a blog post but this content now resides in the manual under https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html see "Permissions Under Marshmallow (Android 6+)".